# Error de lógica del constructor en Java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, constructor, lógica

Estoy recibiendo este error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "back_end.TWorkshop.addaEquipment(back_end.TEquipment)" because "this.val$pWorkshop" is null
at front_end.Equipment$2.actionPerformed(Equipment.java:256)

```
public abstract class TEquipment
{
    protected String aID;   
    protected float aInitial_Cost_Price;
    protected IntArray aHours_Worked; 

protected TEquipment(String pID, float pInitial_Cost_Price, IntArray pHours_Worked) 
{        
    aID = pID; 
    aInitial_Cost_Price = pInitial_Cost_Price;   
    aHours_Worked = pHours_Worked;
}

public class TElectric extends TEquipment
{   
private float aElectrical_Consumption;

public TElectric(String pID, float pInitial_Cost_Price, IntArray pHours_Worked, float pElectrical_Consumption) 
{   
    super(pID, pInitial_Cost_Price, pHours_Worked);   
    aElectrical_Consumption = pElectrical_Consumption;
}

public void addaEquipment(TEquipment pEquipment) 
{     
    aEquipment_List.add(pEquipment);
}
```

Aqui esta especificamente la parte del programa que da error
El error que estoy recibiendo es al presionar el boton para añadir un nuevo equipo
//botón//

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {                   
        String Identifier = textFieldIdentifier.getText();
        String Initial_cost_price = textFieldInitial_cost_price.getText();
        String Monday = textFieldMonday.getText();
        String Sunday = textFieldSunday.getText();                  
        if(comboBoxType.getSelectedIndex()==1)               
        {                   
            String Classification = textFieldClassification.getText();
            if(Identifier.isEmpty() || Initial_cost_price.isEmpty() || Monday.isEmpty() || Tuesday.isEmpty() || Wednesday.isEmpty() || Thursday.isEmpty() || Friday.isEmpty() || Saturday.isEmpty() || Sunday.isEmpty() || Classification.isEmpty())                    
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter all the data");
                }
                else
                {
                    IntArray aHours_Worked = new IntArray();
                    aHours_Worked.add(Integer.valueOf(Monday));
                    aHours_Worked.add(Integer.valueOf(Sunday)); 
                    
                    mechanical = new TMechanical(Identifier, Float.valueOf(Initial_cost_price), aHours_Worked, Classification.charAt(0));                   
                    pWorkshop.addaEquipment(mechanical);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Aggregated " + Identifier + " equipment" + "\nTotal equipment number "  + pWorkshop.getaEquipment_List().size());
                }
            }
            else if(comboBoxType.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                String Electrical_consumption = textFieldElectrical_consumption.getText();
                if(Identifier.isEmpty() || Initial_cost_price.isEmpty() || Monday.isEmpty() || Tuesday.isEmpty() || Wednesday.isEmpty() || Thursday.isEmpty() || Friday.isEmpty() || Saturday.isEmpty() || Sunday.isEmpty() || Electrical_consumption.isEmpty())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter all the data");
                }
                else
                {
                    IntArray aHours_Worked = new IntArray();
                    aHours_Worked.add(Integer.valueOf(Monday));
                    aHours_Worked.add(Integer.valueOf(Sunday)); 
                    
                    electrical = new TElectric(Identifier, Float.valueOf(Initial_cost_price), aHours_Worked, Float.valueOf(Electrical_consumption));                    
                    pWorkshop.addaEquipment(electrical);                       
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Aggregated " + Identifier + " equipment" + "\nTotal equipment number "  + pWorkshop.getaEquipment_List().size());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Select what type the equipment is");
            }                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                               
    });
```

//línea 256//

```
pWorkshop.addaEquipment(electrical);
```

ya le agregue mas detalles del problema

Comment: Dónde inicializa pWorkshop??

Comment: ya agregue la parte del error especificamente no solo los constructores

Comment: no lo inicializo @Alfabravo

Comment: Pues ese es el error. Qué se supone que es ese objeto?

Comment: @Alfabravo lo que se supone que estoy tratando de hacer es crear un nuevo equipo con datos que me da el usuario y agregarlo a un arreglo pero realmente esa parte del error no entiendo bien como funciona que tendria que hacer para arreglarlo

Comment: @Alfabravo aqui adjunto toda mi aplicacion en caso de que hagan falta mas detalles https://github.com/XKorp00/Equipment_Repair_Shop

Comment: Es que es un problema de programación orientada a objetos, no de tu aplicación. Si no declaras ese objeto, cómo lo usas? La clase donde está addEquipment es static?

Comment: Mirando tu código es evidente que nunca inicializas `workshop`. Prueba inicializar esa variable, usando por ejemplo `private TWorkshop workshop = new TWorkshop(new ArrayList<>());` en la línea 36 del archivo Workshop. De cualquier manera tu código tiene bastantes errores de lógica y hasta de sintaxis, empezando por la línea 9 del archivo `TMechanical` la cual está incompleta. ¡Muy buena suerte en arreglar todo ese desmadre!

Comment: @JaimeMenendez gracias ya pude solucionar todo ando aprendiendo Java por eso el millón de errores tontos